# First time hitting REST endpoint through ZUUL returns 403 but subsequent calls work

Tags: spring, spring-security, redis, spring-session, netflix-zuul

I'm literally running out of hair to tear out.
I've tried every flavour of config and still no luck.
I hit Zuul to access a microservice REST endpoint. The first time I hit it, i'm bounced with a 403, after that all is good and I can hit it to hearts content without any issues at all. I'm using all the latest release level dependencies. Is this just a noob mistake or has anyone else seen the issue?

I'm making a GET call to endpoint. The call returns a 403. Then repeating the exact same call, for instance by just refreshing browser, works every time, only very first call is issue.

Spring Boot application, Zuul, and Rest microservice. Using Spring Session and Redis to share authentication with UserDetailsService.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe first time the request cost long time, cause zuul server timeout. you can add below config:

```
# Increase the Hystrix timeout to 60s (globally)
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000
```